# Mistake in the wording of a question about the cardinality of a set of primes?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, fake-proofs

First, I do NOT want the answer to the question, I just need to make sure that there is not a mistake in the wording.

The question states:
[image]

In particular, I think the $p^{k-1}(p-1)$ is wrong.

There are $(p-1)$ non-zero equivalent classes in this problem, each one ocurring in between two consecutive powers of $p$. There are $k$ such intervals, so shouldn't there be $k(p-1)$ such integers?

Comment: The statement is correct.  For example, $\phi(3^2)$ is the cardinality of $\{ 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8 \}$ which is $6 = 3^{2-1} (3-1)$.

Comment: There are not $k$ such intervals and consecutive powers of $p$ are not the only consideration.  Consecutive multiples of $p$ are what is important.

Comment: oh crap that's correct, the powers are not what matters, it's the multiples...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wording is correct.

The p-1 consecutive values
are not between consecutive *powers*
of p
but between consecutive
*multiples* of p.